# Ошибка: "Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения. this было 0x9A2E927C."

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. Вот имеется некоторый код, при запуске которого появляется ошибка "Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения". Помогите пожалуйста! (знаю что код топорный, писал быстро на коленке)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

class Human {
public:

    int deti1;
    int deti2;
    int rodid;
    char namee[20];

    void setname(char pplname[20]) {
        strcpy_s(namee, pplname);
    }

    void  getname() {
        cout << namee;
    }

    void setchilds(int nom1, int nom2) {
        deti1 = nom1;
        if (nom2 != -1) {
            deti2 = nom2;
        }
    }

    int getchild1() {
        return deti1;
    }

    int getchild2() {
        return deti2;
    }

    void setrod(int nom) {
        rodid = nom;
    }

    int getrod() {
        return rodid;
    }
};

int main(){
    int A[100];
    int k = 0;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    Human peoples[12];

    peoples[1].setname("Vasia");
    peoples[2].setname("Kostia");
    peoples[3].setname("Alekseiy");
    peoples[4].setname("Zhenia");
    peoples[5].setname("Sergeiy");
    peoples[6].setname("Natasha");
    peoples[7].setname("Dasha");
    peoples[8].setname("Masha");
    peoples[9].setname("Elena");
    peoples[10].setname("Katia");
    peoples[11].setname("Olia");
    peoples[12].setname("Elia");

    peoples[2].setchilds(4,-1);
    peoples[5].setchilds(2,7);
    peoples[6].setchilds(2,7);
    peoples[7].setchilds(8,-1);
    peoples[10].setchilds(11,1);
    peoples[12].setchilds(4,-1);

    peoples[1].setrod(11);
    peoples[2].setrod(7);
    peoples[3].setrod(5);
    peoples[5].setrod(3);
    peoples[7].setrod(2);
    peoples[11].setrod(1);

    for (int i=1; i<12; i++){

        if (peoples[i].getrod() != 0) {
            if (peoples[peoples[i].getrod()].getchild1() != 0) {
                if          (peoples[peoples[peoples[i].getrod()].getchild1()].getchild1() != 0) {
                    peoples[peoples[peoples[peoples[i].getrod()].getchild1()].getchild1()].getname();
                    cout << " является внучатым племянником (внучатой племянницей) ";
                    peoples[i].getname();
                    cout << endl;
                }
            }
            else {
                if (peoples[peoples[i].getrod()].getchild2() != 0) {
                    if (peoples[peoples[peoples[i].getrod()].getchild2()].getchild2() != 0) {
                        peoples[peoples[peoples[peoples[i].getrod()].getchild2()].getchild2()].getname();
                        cout << " является внучатым племянником (внучатой племянницей) ";
                        peoples[i].getname();
                        cout << endl;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы **абсолютно никак** не инициализируете поля класса - вот там и хранится всякий мусор...

Если уж вы не пишете никакого конструктора - то хотя бы напишите инициализацию

```
int deti1 = 0;
int deti2 = 0;
int rodid = 0;
char namee[20] = "";
```

Без этого у вас может быть что угодно, вплоть до кровосмешения и побочных детей и родителей на стороне... :)

В разборки, кто кому кем приходится, не встревал :), тут разбирайтесь сами.

Comment: Спасибо за совет! А ошибку я уже нашел : нужно было заменить !=0 на >0, т.к. при первом варианте появлялись отрицательные значения.